# Hadoop telnet not working with IP and namenode port

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have set up hadoop in vm and it is working fine.But if try to do telnet using IP and namenode port 9000 from same machine itself then also do not work.

```
telnet 172.23.173.238  9000  ->fails

telnet localhost  9000   -> works
```

I tried different solutions and changed "fs.default.name" in core-site.xml to "hdfs://172.23.173.238:9000" and
"hdfs://0.0.0.0:9000".But nothing is working for me.

Also if I start namenode as,

```
$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [localhost]
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [node01]
```

In line 1 in output I can see "localhost"  ,not sure if it has anything to do with this issue.

Comment: Note: `nc -vz` and `netstat` should be used for port checking, not telnet, for security reasons. In any case, I don't quite understand where this IP you're using comes from... Are you not port forwarding the VM?

Comment: 172.23.173.238 is the IP of the vm. I am trying to connect the namenode process running in the vm from a same  machine. 
Thats when I get error as :-
Connection refused: 172.23.173.238:9000.

Comment: Is the namenode actually running? Use `jps` or look at actual process logs, not just start command output

Comment: Yes. i checked with jps command. If i try "telnet localhost 9000" it works but using IP do not work i.e "telnet 172.23.173.238 9000" fails. Probably somehow hadoop is only working via localhost and loopback address.

Comment: Like I said, you need to port forward a VM, if you're trying to connect from outside of it. Using the external IP of a local machine will always route back to itself, so there's no reason to check it that way... But yes, show your core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml files with an [edit]